# Implementation of Bit-Plane Decomposition c#

Tags: c#, image, algorithm, image-processing

Tried to implement a bpcs-steganography, and one of the first problem i faced was bit-plane decomposition.
I've created a method (GetBitPlaneRed) (only for Red yet, but it seems the same for other colors) which creates a red-and-white bitmap based on the original bitmap and the index of bit plane (from 1 to 8).

```
    private static int GetBit(byte b, int bitIndex)
    {
        return  (b >> bitIndex) & 0x01;
    }


    private static Bitmap GetBitPlaneRed(Bitmap bitmap, int bitPlaneIndex)
    {
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++)
            {
                Color currColor = bitmap.GetPixel(i, j);

                int bit = GetBit(currColor.R, bitPlaneIndex);

                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255 * bit, 255 * bit);

                newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
            }
        }
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Seems, it works allright for the MSB (most significant bit), but for other bit planes it's not so correct. Here are some result pictures that i've got to comparison with the right ones.

**[EDIT]** The "right results" are from a scientific [article](http://datahide.org/BPCSe/principle-e.html) about BPCS steganography written by *Eiji Kawaguchi*, so i trust that source. Also, it seems that the mistake is in the way i save my bit-plane images, so i've added some peace of code here where i save my bit-plane images.
Added an original image as well.

```
    private static void SaveBitPlanes()
    {           
        string filePath = "monalisa.jpg";            
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath);

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filePath);
        ImageFormat imageFormat = bitmap.RawFormat;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Bitmap newBitmap = GetBitPlaneRed(bitmap, i);  
            newBitmap.Save("bitPlaneRed" + i + ext, imageFormat);
        }           
    }
```

Original image:

[image]

My result of MSB plane:

[image]

My result of bit plane #3:

[image]

My result of bit plane #7:

[image]

Right results:
[image]

I would appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: I think your only problem is that you're using a jpeg resave of the original source, and not the actual source... your bit plane #7 image clearly shows jpeg artifacts on areas that are practically pure black, and the "right results" image you showed has clear signs of jpeg compression damage in it.

Comment: The code has an operator precedence bug, use `(1 << (bitIndex - 1))` instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for finding this mistake, but unfortunatelly that changes nothing

Comment: [Arithmetic operations have higher priority than bitshifts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx), so the brackets don't change anything. Can you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates your problem? We'll need the original image you load, along with the call to the function for a specific bit-plane you're not satisfied with. And where did you get those claimed right results?

Comment: @Reti43 Edited post according to your advice.

Comment: Your code produces the correct results for the image you provided. I don't see anywhere on the site where they provide a copy of the image they used. If you just got a copy from somewhere else on the internet, it is likely that image comes from a different photographic source and may have also been compressed, filtered or reshaped. All these factors means no two versions of the same image guarantee the pixels will be exactly the same. But your code is fine.

Comment: @Reti43 Thanks for all your help, i appreciate it! Tried bigger image, and in that case my result were familiar to those in an article. So, question is answered, thanks everybody for help once more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all important stuff I figured out during existance of this question.

- All code I wrote in main post is correct.
- Difference in images is not connected with jpeg compression or any
  other compression. It works for any file format.
- The reason why my results were not similar to those results in an
  article is that I used a low-quality image as a source. After I tried
  some other high quality images, results look nice and pretty
  detailed.
- Thank everybody for helping me in figuring out all these points!